# xml parsing with Post method+iphone

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, nsmutableurlrequest

I am having problem with xmlparsing with post method.

```
API URL :  http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/api/user.php
Function Name : getUserList
Sample XML :
<root>
    <data>
        <id>0</id>
        <search></search>
    </data>
</root>
```

Now i am using :-

```
// setting up the URL to post to
NSString *urlString = @"http://XXX.XXX.X.XX/api/user.php";

// setting up the request object now
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

But how should i make the post HTMLbody part in this..

Means where and how should i put functional name and sample xml in the code

***My Edited Question is*** :-

```
  NSString *urlString = @" http://192.168.6.79/silverAPI/api/user.php/getUserList";

    // setting up the request object now
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString * str = @"<root><data><id>0</id><search>a</search></data></root>";
    NSString * message= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/getUserList mydata=%@", str];
    [request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];





    // now lets make the connection to the web
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"Responce==>%@",returnString);
```

But i getting black in responce.Pleaseee help me out..
is my

```
 NSString *urlString = @" http://192.168.6.79/silverAPI/api/user.php/getUserList";
```

And

> NSString * str =
>   @"0a";
>       NSString * message= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/getUserList
>   mydata=%@", str];
>       [request setHTTPBody:[message
>   dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
>       [request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8"
>   forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

This part of code is correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set html body using method `- (void)setHTTPBody:(NSData *)data`. For example:

```
[request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

where message is,in your case, xml.

Also you need to add this code to help server to determine type of sent data:

```
[request addValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

If you want to set some additional flags to your request you can use method `- (void)setValue:(NSString *)value forHTTPHeaderField:(NSString *)field`.

Comment: Thank for the quick reply.Can u give me the idea how should i get the responce data.I had used this.Please guide me whether it is proper:-NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: It looks ok, but why don't you want to check returning response code?

Comment: I want to check that whether the responce i m getting throigh this is proper or not

Comment: @Nikto Thanks for the reply and help.my request is :-NSString *message=@"getUserList;data=<root><data><id>0</id><search>a</search></data></root>";
  [request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
I am geting black in responce string.I am should i need to add somthing like this:-[request setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

Comment: Are you sure that your server expects xml in `mydata`? ` NSString * message= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/getUserList mydata=%@", str];`? And i think, you should remove "/getUserList "

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3653/discussion-between-shweta-and-nekto)

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is perfect, please check on server side whether response from there is coming properly by sending the same request or not.